# Child gameobject text

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck trying to store the input from a text gameobject child , i don't know the exact syntax to do it , i will post here the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Username : MonoBehaviour {

        public string username;

        public void writing()
        {
        // get text component from UsernameInputField

                transform.Find ("UsernameInputField/Text");

        // store the input from the user in the username string





        }
}
```

With the transform.find I've already get the Text gameonject , yet i need some tips to store the input from the user in the username variable.
The same will apply for the password script that i will do in another file.

Going to leave here a screenshot of the hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it, but I would recommend that you add nullchecks and validate that the textfields have valid input.

```
username = transform.Find ("UsernameInputField/Text").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
password = transform.Find ("PasswordInputField/Text").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :) , one more thing if possible , do you have some site or tutorial where i can learn about those nullchecks and validations ?